# How to set monitoring properties in order to moniitor a rest interface with PRTG?

Tags: arcgis-server

I am trying to use PRTG as a monitoring tool for ArcGIS Server 10.3.1 Rest interfaces.

I am having problems finding the correct sensor to add to the PRTG Map in order to monitor a Rest endpoint correctly.

In the properties section on the sensor I have to enter 2 different values

- 1. URL and
- 2. XML - Node (and optional Properties).

I have entered the URL of a service as displayed in the picture.

[image]

I am a bit confused about the XML-Node - as the rest interface returns JSON.

Comment: The monitoring software PRTG has many use cases and applications in different areas. The successful application of PRTG in a GIS environment would involve having knowledge of GIS server software systems, GIS databases, and GIS network interfaces in order to create the appropriate sensors. This knowledge would probably not be available else where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using in PRTG the "advanced http sensor", you can check for some json content like:

[image]